# How can I create .mobileconfig file programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios11

Basically, I want to store my wifi information only SSID and PASSWORD to `.mobileconfig` for next time that allows the user to connect to the specified SSID wifi network.

I have no idea how to create `.mobileconfig` to the iOS app programmatically.

**do I miss anything? please leave a comment your hints may be helped to figure my problem**

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can generate by creating an XML file, with content like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>AutoJoin</key>
            <true/>
            <key>CaptiveBypass</key>
            <false/>
            <key>DisableAssociationMACRandomization</key>
            <false/>
            <key>EncryptionType</key>
            <string>WPA</string>
            <key>HIDDEN_NETWORK</key>
            <false/>
            <key>IsHotspot</key>
            <false/>
            <key>Password</key>
            <string>PASSWORD</string>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string>Configures Wi-Fi settings</string>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>Wi-Fi</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.wifi.managed.04D6D3F5-5DE2-40A3-9F41-E405186DD226</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.wifi.managed</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>04D6D3F5-5DE2-40A3-9F41-E405186DD226</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>ProxyType</key>
            <string>None</string>
            <key>SSID_STR</key>
            <string>SSID</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>Sample</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>yourname.profileid</string>
    <key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```